# SVG text-anchor setting in inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

I just wanted to know where is the setting to set text-anchor svg property in inkscape. I wanted to align the text. But Inkskape is doing it in its own way by adding a tspan element.

Comment: why don't you just edit your .svg file in text editor? Add your attributes to your text element as wanted... I often work on .svg files, but manually... with text-editor... never with inkscape... or maybe try the google svg-edit tool, that may be easier to find what you need... GL

Comment: Actually it is for the designing team, who was not families with XML

Comment: Now I decided to do it programatically but I encounter another problem. can you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379389/svg-text-anchor-setting-makes-the-text-element-to-move