# SVG text-anchor setting makes the text element to move

Tags: javascript, svg

Hello I am trying to set the text-anchor of an SVG text element.
But when I do that, the text elements position is changing. I read its "x" attribute but it remains same. but getBBox() gives different values.

My question:
How do I reposition the text element? is there any method to set the BBox?
I am using JQuery and JQuery SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are misunderstanding how the `text-anchor` attribute works.  It tells the renderer how the text should be positioned relative to the poisition you specify with `x` and `y`.  If you change it, the position of the text will change relative to `x` & `y`.

You can read its definition here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#AlignmentProperties

> How do I reposition the text element?

You use the `x` and `y` attributes.  You can also use the `transform` attribute.

> is there any method to set the BBox?

No.  The bounding box is read-only.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will use the transform for this.